# Chart.js - horizontal alignment of multiple canvas-elements

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have multiple dynamically created canvas - elements using chart.js.
All elements have the same structure (but different chart data).

Chart.js is not rendering them with the same alignment, as shown in the attached image. Is there a way to set something like 'alignment - left' in chart.js?
[image]

Edit: Sourcecode:

Generated HTML:

```
<canvas id="chartQ1"></canvas>
<script>DrawChart("chartQ1",
    [
        "Answer 1",
        "Answer 2",
        "Answer 3",
        "Answer 4"
    ],[
        "2",
        "1",
        "2",
        "0"
    ],[
        "rgba(0,150,64,0.2)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)",
        "rgba(0,150,64,0.2)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)"
    ],[
        "rgba(0,150,64,0.8)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)",
        "rgba(0,150,64,0.8)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)"
    ])
<canvas id="chartQ2"></canvas>
<script>DrawChart("chartQ2",
    [
        "{a,b,e,f}",
        "{c,d}",
        "{e,f}",
        "{}"
    ],[
        "2",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0"
    ],[
        "rgba(0,150,64,0.2)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)"
    ],[
        "rgba(0,150,64,0.8)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)"
    ])
</script>
```

Function used to create graphs:

```
function DrawChart(canvasID, remoteFields, remoteData, remoteColors, remoteBorderColors) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById(canvasID).getContext('2d');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: remoteFields,
        datasets: [{
            data: remoteData,
            backgroundColor: remoteColors,
            borderColor: remoteBorderColors,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               callback: function(t) {
                  var maxLabelLength = 25;
                  if (t.length > maxLabelLength) return t.substr(0, maxLabelLength) + '...';
                  else return t;
               }
            }
         }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                                        stepSize: 1
                }
            }]
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
        display: false
    },
        tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            title: function(t, d) {
               return d.labels[t[0].index];
            }
         }
      }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Pineda edited my question

Comment: Have you defined any CSS for the canvas tags or their containers?

Comment: @Pineda no, they are all equally created. When I view them in the developer tools, they all have the same margin / padding, just the content inside the canvas is unidentical, so I though chart.js could create its own paddings, maybe.